# Why does move use a spawn trigger?

Tags: spwn

I was coding in [SPWN](https://spu7nix.net/spwn/#/) and heres the code i have:

```
let bob = 1g
let key = 1i
let amount = 20
bob.move(amount, 100, 1)
```

When I ran it, it said 2 triggers and not one, and that one is a spawn trigger.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with moving? What happens if you take out the `move` call?

Comment: Looking at the [triggers article](https://geometry-dash.fandom.com/wiki/Triggers#Object_triggers) on the Geometry Dash wiki, I think the spawn trigger is needed to control the activation time of the move trigger. I've never done anything with Geometry Dash, though, so I could be misinterpreting something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined Bob as `Bob = 1g`. So we know that Bob is a group, since groups are denoted by `g`, based on the variables section of the [documentation](https://spu7nix.net/spwn/#/triggerlanguage/1variables) you provided.

From the triggers article that user2357112 commented:

> Spawn triggers activate a certain group of triggers that are marked "Spawn Triggered". When activated, the group to be activated will be triggered at the same time

This means that, when telling Bob to do something, you are activating his entire group to do something- this is the ‘spawn trigger’ you mentioned. You can think of a `spawn trigger` as activating other triggers, and technically this trigger is what allows the move trigger to have more intricate features attached to it, like a delay.

The move trigger:

> Move triggers are triggers that move certain groups of objects around in a level

You now move Bob (group `g`) 20 units on the x-axis and 100 units on the y-axis, in 1 second (20, 100, 1). This is trigger #2. This is called a ‘move trigger’, sometimes referred to as just a ‘trigger’.

So the spawn trigger activated bobs group, while the move trigger moves bobs group.

Two triggers.